# `GetJREPath()` when installing IntelliJ via command line OSX

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, installation, mount, finder

I was trying to be able to install Intellj hands free by running this:

```
wget https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-2017.2.3.dmg
hdiutil mount -nobrowse ideaIC-2017.2.3.dmg
mkdir /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app
cp -r /Volumes/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/ /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/
hdiutil unmount /Volumes/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE/ 
rm ideaIC-2017.2.3.dmg
```

I notice when installing on OSX and the `Intellij.app` file gets coppied from the mount in `/Volumes/IntelliJ` into a dir in my `/Applications` folder from the command line with `cp`, I have the error:

```
Error: could not find libjava.dylib
Failed to GetJREPath()
```

When running the executable file in `/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/MacOS`.

Specifically, I got:

`LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app.`

when I tried to:

`open /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/`

But none of this goes wrong when I try manually "drag-and-drop" the app from the Finder window. What's going on here?

Info:

Output when I "drag-and-drop":

```
./idea 
2017-08-31 18:14:27.258 idea[5098:151348] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2017-08-31 18:14:27.260 idea[5098:151359] Value of IDEA_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2017-08-31 18:14:27.260 idea[5098:151359] fullFileName is: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
2017-08-31 18:14:27.260 idea[5098:151359] fullFileName exists: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
2017-08-31 18:14:27.260 idea[5098:151359] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
2017-08-31 18:14:27.260 idea[5098:151359] Done
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.properties: 'java.endorsed.dirs = ' already defined in system properties: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed
```

Output when I `mkdir` then `cp`:

```
./idea 
2017-08-31 18:15:56.295 idea[5134:152286] allVms required 1.8*,1.8+
2017-08-31 18:15:56.297 idea[5134:152301] Value of IDEA_VM_OPTIONS is (null)
2017-08-31 18:15:56.297 idea[5134:152301] fullFileName is: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
2017-08-31 18:15:56.297 idea[5134:152301] fullFileName exists: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
2017-08-31 18:15:56.297 idea[5134:152301] Processing VMOptions file at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions
2017-08-31 18:15:56.298 idea[5134:152301] Done
Error: could not find libjava.dylib
Failed to GetJREPath()
2017-08-31 18:15:56.298 idea[5134:152301] JNI_CreateJavaVM (/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jdk) failed: 4294967295
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the following command instead:

```
cp -R /Volumes/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/ /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ CE.app/
```

Notice `-R` option instead of `-r`.

According to [this man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html), `-r` works differently on macOS:

> COMPATIBILITY
>
> Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation supports that option; however, **its use is strongly discouraged**, as it **does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or
> fifo's.**